# How can I animate border width / color of UICollectionViewCells during layout transition?

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that uses a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. This in turn uses a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` with properties that affect things like border color and thickness on the cells. When performing an animated layout change on my collection view, how can I include these things in the animations?

**Implementation details:**

Say in `MyLayoutAttributes` I have an enum property `LayoutType` with values `TypeBig` and `TypeSmall`. I have a cell class `MyCell` with a `UILabel` as a subview.  In that cell class, I do something like this:

```
-(void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attr
{
  [super applyLayoutAttributes:attr];
  MyLayoutAttributes *myAttr = (MyLayoutAttributes *)attr;
  if (myAttr.layoutType == TypeSmall)
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1; //there's already a color set
  else
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0;
}
```

When the collection view's layout changes (using `[collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:animated:]`), the cell size and position changes are animated as expected, but the border is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, changes to layer properties are not caught by the animation methods on `UIView` like `animateWithDuration`. So they have to be added to the layer using `CAAnimation`. So, in `applyLayoutAttributes`, I do something like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"borderColor"];
anim.fromValue = (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
anim.toValue = (id)[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
anim.duration = [CATransaction animationDuration];
anim.timingFunction = [CATransaction animationTimingFunction];
[self.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"myAnimation"];
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28225575/412107) for the trick about getting the right animation duration.